# Unity window button theme specification?

Tags: unity

I'm trying to track down the specification of Unity window button themes.
**By this I mean the specification specific to Unity**, (`/usr/share/themes/Radiance/unity`), **not** the gtk or metacity specifications (`/usr/share/themes/Radiance/metacity-1` or `/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-x.0`).

The only themes I've found that appear to use this specification are the Radiance and Ambiance ones (in package `light-themes`).

Upon looking in `/usr/share/themes/(Ambiance|Radiance)/unity`, I see the images:

- role.png
- role_focusstate_state.png

where

- `role` is one of `close`, `maximize`, `minimize` or `unmaximize`;
- `focusstate` is `focused` or `unfocused`;
- `state` is `normal`, `prelight` or `pressed`.

**Is there some specification on how to create a unity window theme? Which of the above files is required at minimum? when each is used?**

(For example, is the `close.png` ever used if `close_[focusstate]_[state].png` exists for all focus states and states already? If so, when? If not, why is `close.png` included with Ambiance/Radiance, which appear to cover all focus states and all states already?)

Comment: I hope someone competent answers you :) There is the possibility that some icons are vestigial and have no role currently. You may already have tried this, but I rename stuff and if nothing breaks over a while, I get the feeling that it isn't needed at least with my usage pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done a bit more digging, and I suspect that:

- unity uses the metacity theme (`metacity-1` subfolder) for **all window decorations**;
- unity uses the `unity` subfolder to draw window buttons **in the top unity panel only** (when a window is maximized and the titlebar has been hidden (?))

(I don't currently have Unity available to me to test).

The relevant bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/740232

In particular, comment 22:

> This has been fixed. Check /usr/share/themes/ambiance/unity, you'll find buttons there which are loaded into panel. So, yes Unity window control buttons are now themable.

The relevant code (3/Jun/2013): http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-team/unity/trunk/view/3355/unity-shared/PanelStyle.cpp#L197

**I do not believe there is any documentation**.

However, reading the relevant code (above) it seems like

- The window button types are `CLOSE`, `MINIMIZE`, `UNMAXIMIZE`, `MAXIMIZE`
- The window button states are `NORMAL`, `PRELIGHT`, `PRESSED`, `DISABLED`, `UNFOCUSED`, `UNFOCUSED_PRELIGHT`, `UNFOCUSED_PRESSED`

These seem much the same as metacity.

To find the image corresponding to the button with type `type` and state `state`, we look up `unity/<type_><state_>.png`, where:

- `type_` is:

  - 'close' for type `CLOSE`;
  - 'minimize' for type `MINIMIZE`;
  - 'maximize' for type `MAXIMIZE`;
  - 'unmaximize' for type `UNMAXIMIZE`.
- `state_` is:

  - '' (nothing) for state `NORMAL` (a button on the active window);
  - '_focused_prelight' for state `PRELIGHT` (a button on the active window that is being hovered over);
  - '_focused_pressed' for state `PRESSED` (a button on the active window that is being pressed);
  - '_unfocused' for state `DISABLED`; (??)
  - '_unfocused' for state `UNFOCUSED` (a button on an unfocused window);
  - '_unfocused_prelight' for state `UNFOCUSED_PRELIGHT`(a button on an unfocused window that is being hovered over);
  - '_unfocused_pressed' for state `UNFOCUSED_PRESSED` (a button on an unfocused window that is being pressed).

Hence note that of the images in the `unity` subfolder of (say) Ambiance, `<role>_focused_normal.png` **is not used**, even though it's provided in the package (??).

If the image for a particular (type, state) is not found, it looks like some sort of default button is drawn (rather than using one of the existing images).